# ESP32-C3 RF pin design question

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, antenna, schematics, esp32

I have a question regarding the ESP32-C3.

I would like to have a transmission and receiver antenna in my system. The transmission antenna needs to be close to isotropic and the receiver must be very directional, hence the need of two antennas.

Now, looking at the pinout, pin1 is LNA_IN which is a *RF IN and Out*.

**How can I have the two antennas in the design if I only have one pin?**

I saw a T/R switch to be suggested, but I need both antennas to be functional the whole time.

Datasheet: [ESP32-C3 Series](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_datasheet_en.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most (but not all) RF transceivers, the ESP32 can not receive and transmit at the same time. Internally it has an RF switch that connects the LNA_IN pin to the receiver when receiving, and to the transmitter when transmitting.

The only practical way to use different antennas is to add an external RF switch that is synchronized to the transmit/receive mode of the ESP32. I don't know if the ESP32 is capable of providing that mode signal externally; you would have to dig into the firmware.

There is a somewhat exotic RF device called a *circulator* which can send incoming and outgoing signals to different ports. In theory it could accomplish what you requested, but in practice the isolation achievable is probably not sufficient to protect the receiver from being overwhelmed by the transmitted signal.